# How do you know the latest chromecast device build?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

A user of mine is reporting that there is a new chromecast version and my app broke. I have 4 different devices and they all have build 16041, but I have no idea where to check if that is the latest. I've tried rebooting all 4 of them already.

So is there a page or blog where that is listed?

Also as a bonus question, is there a way to get updates for when the Cast Companion Library is updated? or the sdk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no page to tell you what the latest build is; new builds go out in batches like other updates so not everyone gets them all at the very same time.

As your second question, register yourself on Github for that project to be notified when there is a commit.

In future, it is best if you open different StackOverflow questions for different questions.

Comment: Can you confirm if 16041 is the current production build? I have a feeling my user reporting this is confused but I can't tell him that unless I'm certain.

Comment: Yes, 16041 is the latest build that is being rolled out right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the build using the Chromecast app for Android or iOS.
Once the app detects a device, select it and then, at the very bottom of the information view, you'll find the build number of the device's firmware.

Comment: Yes but that isn't necessarily the latest version google is shipping, google likes to do staged rollout of updates on most things.

Comment: The Chromecast device updates itself automatically when it detects that there's a new update.

Comment: Yes it does but as Ali Naddaf mentioned it is done in batches and not everyone gets it right away.